# posix mutexes not working as expected

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, mutex

I have a problem.

I have a static mutex initialized and trying to lock it in all of my functions.
I accidently forgot to unlock it in one of the functions, but it seems that there is no deadlock taking place when i call another function that also tries to acquire the mutex lock.

Can someone please explain me why is it this way that deadlock is not occuring?

Code explaining my scenario of problem:

```
 pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

 void main(void)
 {
   func1();  // Mutex acquired initially but not released at end
   func2();  // This function acquires mutex even though mutex was not released by func1();

 }


 void func1(void)
 {
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

   printf("I am in func1\n");

   //MUTEX NOT UNLOCKED
 }

 void func2(void)
 {
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

   printf("I am in func2\n");

   //MUTEX AGAIN NOT UNLOCKED
 }
```

Can someone please explian me why is deadlock not taking place in func2() as mutex was not released in func1()  ?

Comment: yes, I am using PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER only to initialize mutex. Actually, my functions are much more complicated but the idea is the same, that is, no deadlock is occuring. I just want to make sure that if I have threads called in main(), they should have access to func1 and func2 in a synchronized manner.

Comment: Does the example you posted here display this behavior too or just the much more complicated functions? After I fixed it so it compiles it deadlocks just fine on two different operating systems and aborts on third.

Comment: Yes, the behavior is same, that's why I posted the simplified version of my program, that makes easier for others to understand.

Comment: It this on Linux using gcc? Make sure you use `-pthread` as a build option.

Comment: Hey I was not using -lpthread in my Makefile. I found the bug and now mutxes are working perfectly. Thanks everyone for your help and suggestion.

Comment: func1 and func2 are called from the same thread. Locking a mutex will result in success when the thread "owned" the mutex already.

Answer (score 2):

According to the specification, PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER is equivalent to a default mutex:

> In cases where default mutex attributes are appropriate, the macro
>   PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER can be used to initialise mutexes that are
>   statically allocated. The effect is equivalent to dynamic
>   initialisation by a call to pthread_mutex_init() with parameter attr
>   specified as NULL, except that no error checks are performed.

And for default mutexes, attempting to lock a mutex that has been locked by the calling thread leads to undefined behaviour:

> If the mutex type is PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT, attempting to recursively
>   lock the mutex results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: To elaborate, it sounds like on OP's system, `PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT` is a recursive mutex rather than a regular one (which would deadlock) or an error-checking one (which would return an error).

Comment: I didn't really get your explaination. Can you please explain it with respect to my posted code. 


You mean to say that I make the initialization of mutex static?

Comment: When you use `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`, it's as if you pass NULL to `pthread_mutex_init()`. This is equivalent to passing the default mutex attributes object. This is the same as the object you get from `pthread_mutexattr_init()`. You can see what type you are getting by using `pthread_mutexattr_gettype()` on this object. On my system I'm getting `PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT`. So on that system, attempting the lock the same mutex twice from the same thread leads to undefined behaviour (may work, may lock, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock

> If the mutex type is PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT, attempting to recursively
>   lock the mutex results in undefined behavior.

Your program has [undefined behavior](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213) and so *may* suddenly output "Formatting root partition, chomp chomp"... who knows.

Comment: But in my program mutex type isn't PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT. Should I change it to PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT instead of PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER?

Comment: @sam32: `In cases where default mutex attributes are appropriate, the macro PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER can be used to initialize mutexes that are statically allocated. The effect shall be equivalent to dynamic initialization by a call to pthread_mutex_init() with parameter attr specified as NULL, except that no error checks are performed.` and `If attr is NULL, the default mutex attributes are used; ` http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_init

Comment: So essentially, PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER infers PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT. You need to call pthread_mutex_init() to create any other mutex type.